# can't remove GlobalLayoutListener from a view

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to build a controller for my images view that would take just an `ImageView` and a business object as input and deal with onCick events, background, default image, error management and Picasso. I would like to have a generic way to get the actual pixel sizes of an image view for it to be sent to my Medias webservices.

I've read on several stackoverflow posts that said I could use a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` to do so :
public class PicassoController {

```
private final static String TAG = "PicassoController";
private final boolean clic;

private final Context ctx;
private final ImageView iv;
private RecognizedMedia recognizedMedia;

private int height = -1;
private int width = -1;
int i = 0;

public PicassoController(final ImageView imageView, final RecognizedMedia media, boolean clic) {
    this.ctx = imageView.getContext();
    this.iv = imageView;
    this.clic = clic;
    this.recognizedMedia = media;

    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

                height = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
                width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();

                i++;
                Log.i(TAG, "onGlobalLayout : " + i);

                init();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }

        }
    });
}

private void init() {
    if (recognizedMedia == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (recognizedMedia instanceof Media) {
        init((Media) recognizedMedia);
        if (clic) {
            LinkedMediaUtils.dealWithLinkedMedia(((Media) recognizedMedia).getLinkedMedia(), iv);
        }
    }
}

private void init(Media mMedia) {...}

public View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener() {...}

public interface RecognizedMedia {}
```

}

onGlobalLayout is called twiced a second, and is never removed.

Also if you have an opinion about how to write my controller class I'd be glad to here it.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: is it maybe necessary to declare the imageView as final?

Comment: I use `iv` which is a class member so reference is well kept. Also the logs are displayed with the incremented var. I gave it a shot anyway, no differences unfortunatly :(